# executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apk add --update nodejs nodejs-npm]: exit code: 1

Tags: sh

Please help me out to fix this error while building a docker image using this command,

```
docker build -t my-first-app .
```

My Dockerfile content is

```
FROM alpine
LABEL maintainer="aamirpinger@yahoo.com"
RUN apk add --update nodejs nodejs-npm
COPY . /src
WORKDIR /src
RUN npm install
ENV CREATEDBY="Amir Pinger"
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["node", "./app.js"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1125969/how-to-install-npm-in-alpine-linux) question:

> For the recent versions of Alpine (v3.8+) the correct way to install nodejs with npm is:
>
> apk add --update nodejs npm
>
> However, npm package depends on nodejs, so you can do:
>
> apk add --update npm
>
> Note: since Alpine 3.8 there is no nodejs-npm package.

Comment: I tried all methods, at the end I just try using an older version of alpine3.13.